# Disable Command-Up/Down Arrow on OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I disable the Command-Up/Down arrow shortcuts?

I'm tired of jumping to the beginning or end of a document due to years and years of conditioning on other OS's!

Comment: +1 indeed. I also wish there was a universal way of controlling Pg Up/Down, Home and End function in OSX - it's honestly the biggest thing that keeps me away from that otherwise decent OS.

Comment: It's driving me _nuts_. Happy with everything except the lack of a tiling window manager, and the terrible pgup/down/home/end situation.

Comment: Yeah. Something else I find sorta funny is on a VM on OSX, say for Windows or Linux, those keys function as you'd expect. Not surprising, but it still kind of adds insult to injury for me.

Comment: I know the same keys do folder navigation in Finder, so it seems that it's absolutely App overridable -- hence hoping there's a nice shortcut customization program that will help...

Comment: By Occams Razor, do I ever hope so.

Comment: Good luck, it gets even worse on a laptop where the arrows and home/end/pgup/pgdn are shared based on if you hit the Fn button or not (part of why I'm glad to use (Mac)Vim for as much text editing as possible to help steer clear of those arrow keys when typing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could save something like this as `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
    "@\UF700" = noop:; // command-up
    "@\UF701" = noop:; // command-down
    "$@\UF700" = noop:; // shift-command-up
    "$@\UF701" = noop:; // shift-command-down

    // "\UF729"  = moveToBeginningOfLine:; // home
    // "$\UF729" = moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:; // shift-home
    // "\UF72B"  = moveToEndOfLine:; // end
    // "$\UF72B" = moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:; // shift-end
    // "\UF72C"  = pageUp:; // OS X default is scrollPageUp: which doesn't move the caret
    // "\UF72D"  = pageDown:;
    // "$\UF72C"  = pageUpAndModifySelection:;
    // "$\UF72D"  = pageDownAndModifySelection:;
}
```

More information:

- [Cocoa Text System](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html)
- [Keybindings - Lri.me](http://lri.me/keybindings)

Comment: I can't check yet, but **awesome**.

Comment: Could you add some more information about what's going on here - are those last 8 lines commented out (are they required?), what is noop:;?

Comment: See this blog post for a full description: https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/os-x-text-system-keybindings/4929

Comment: I created /Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict as described here and rebooted, and nothing changed.  I'm on Ventura 13.4.1.  Currently I'm unable to find any way to disable command-up/down.